# Camel - Using beans available in jar

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am using Spring's Application context for bean registry. I will be dependent on external jars for some services, which will be a part of routes.

Is there any way to let camel auto-register the beans that are available in the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can call any java class from Camel using its bean component. You can specify a class name, and a method to invoke.

You can use the beanType attribute

```
<bean beanType="com.foo.MyClass" method="someNameHere"/>
```

Or in an uri

```
<to uri="bean:com.foo.MyClass?method=someNameHere"/>
```